# Material UI ToggleButtonGroup

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I am using the Material UI's ToggleButtonGroup feature, however I cannot figure out how to get values passed into my React's state. Below is my code, my  can properly change state's date, however but  does not. I would like the ToggleButtonGroup to work exactly as Select does here, as it matches my UI better. Please help me identify what I am doing incorrect here.

```
state = {
    text: '',
    date: ''
}

handleChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({
        [event.target.name]: event.target.value
    })
}

handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()

    // If input field empty, do nothing.
    if (this.state.text === '') {
        return
    }

    // Submit the form. (Add category here?)
    this.props.onSubmit({
        id: shortid.generate(),
        text: this.state.text,
        date: this.state.date,
        complete: false
    })

    // Empty out input field after todo has been submitted.
    this.setState({
        text: ''
    })
}
            <Select onChange={this.handleChange} name="date" id="date-select" variant="standard">
                <MenuItem value=""></MenuItem>
                <MenuItem value="today">Today</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem value="tomorrow">Tomorrow</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem value="week">This week</MenuItem>
            </Select>
            <ToggleButtonGroup onChange={this.handleChange} value="date" name="date" id="date-select" exclusive={true} size="small">
                <ToggleButton value="today">Today</ToggleButton>
                <ToggleButton value="tomorrow">Tomorrow</ToggleButton>
                <ToggleButton value="week">This week</ToggleButton>
            </ToggleButtonGroup>
```

Answer (score 1):

With `ToggleButtonGroup` on `onChange` callback there are two params expected, first one is event, and the other one is selected value, we can customize that

```
handleChange = (name, newValue /*Value of the selected button*/) => {
    console.log(newValue); //value of the selected button
    this.setState({
        [name]: newValue
    })
}
```

so if `handleChange` is common for `Select` and `ToggleButtonGroup` then change it like this.

```
<Select onChange={(e) => this.handleChange("date", e.target.value)} ...

<ToggleButtonGroup onChange={(e, value) => this.handleChange("date", value)}..
```